ValueError: <class 'RuntimeError'>: "object unbound" while evaluating in Odoo 16 when I try to use http.request.session from a cronjob
I try to call the session object in Odoo from a cronjob call
<odoo noupdate="1">
<record id="cron_check_timeout_session" model="ir.cron">
    <field name="name">Check expired sessions</field>
    <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_admin"/>
    <field name="interval_number">1</field>
    <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
    <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    <field name="nextcall" eval="datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)"/>
    <field name="model_id" ref="hr_zk_attendance.model_zk_machine"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">model.check_session_timeout()</field>
</record>

@api.model
def check_session_timeout(self):
    cookies = http.request.session
    _logger.info(f"\x1b[32;21m{cookies}")

But I get this error ValueError: <class 'RuntimeError'>: "object unbound" while evaluating
This only happens when a cronjob triggers automatically, but if I press the manual button the task gets executed successfully

Because there is no session when a cron is running automatically.

How could I work this out?

For what do you need this check?

I want to make the Odoo session expired after a given time, in order to do that I new to be able to access the session object.

But there is no session. AFAIK and simply explained, the cron threads run in a special environment without sessions. In worker mode odoo has special threads for the cron workers. If you want them killed after a specific runtime, the only config setting i know of is --limit-time-real-cron. It's not documented here but you'll find it in code. It's default value is --limit-time-real.

What about the SESSION_LIFETIME?
